# Storing elasticsearch snapshots in amazon s3 repository. How does it work

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have an elasticsearch 2.3 installed on my local Linux machine.
I have Amazon S3 storage: I know region, bucketname, accesskey and secretkey.

I want to make a snapshot of elasticsearch indexes in my S3 storage. There is documentation about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/cloud-aws-repository.html), but it doesn't explain me anything (I am totally new in it.).

So, for example, I am trying to execute this command:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "s3",
 "settings": {"bucket": "ilyabackuptest1", "region": "us-east-1" }}'
```

And I get a response:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "repository_exception",
      "reason" : "[my_s3_repository] failed to create repository"
    } ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[my_s3_repository] failed to create repository",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Unknown [repository] type [s3]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

So how does it work?

**UPDATE:**
After installing repository-s3 I use the same command and get this. How should it work?

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "process_cluster_event_timeout_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to process cluster event (put_repository [my_s3_repository]) within 30s"
    } ],
    "type" : "process_cluster_event_timeout_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to process cluster event (put_repository [my_s3_repository]) within 30s"
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to install the [S3 repository plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.6/repository-s3.html) first:

```
bin/plugin install repository-s3
```

Then you can run again your command to create the S3 repo.

Comment: There is no elasticsearch-plugin file in bin, so this command can not be executed. How can I install this plugin?

Comment: It doesn't work for me too. bin/plugin: No such file or directory

Comment: Of course you need to cd  into your ES installation folder ;-)

Comment: You also probably have to add your AWS `access_key` and `secret_key` to the repository definition: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.6/repository-s3-repository.html